# Get size of uploading file C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fileinfo

I'am trying create some validation for file size. My code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FotoModel model)
    {
        TryUpdateModel(model);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model != null && model.File != null)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(model.File.FileName);
                var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                long fileSize = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
                fileName = "file" + fileExtension;
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), fileName);
                if (fileSize < 55000)
                {
                    model.File.SaveAs(path);
                    model.link = fileName.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["Size"] = "Akceptowane pliki: jpg, jpeg, png o maksymalnym rozmiarze 50 KB";
                }

                return View(model);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

And in this line:

```
long fileSize = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
```

I'am receiving error: "File cannot be found". Do You know how can I resolved this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Asp.Net MVC we have to use `HttpPostedFileBase` for Uploaded files as shown below :-

```
public ActionResult Index(FotoModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
  if (file != null)
        {
            int byteCount = file.ContentLength;  // <---Your file Size or Length
            .............
            .............
        }
}
```

Comment: Could You tell what is "Empdoc" variable ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is a [ContentLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    public ActionResult Index(FotoModel model)
    {
        if (model != null && model.File != null)
        {
            var fileSize = model.File.ContentLength;
        }
    }
```